# Glibc static linking

Tags: perl, glibc, static-linking

I have tried to install Perl module, and at some point I get this error:

```
    chmod 644 SSH2.bs
rm -f blib/arch/auto/Net/SSH2/SSH2.so
LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/lib:/lib" cc  -shared -O2 -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector SSH2.o  -o blib/arch/auto/Net/SSH2/SSH2.so   \
       -L/root -L/usr/local/lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local -L/usr/lib -L/usr -L/opt -L//lib -L/ -lssh2 -lz -lssl -lcrypto      \

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/Net/SSH2/SSH2.so] Error 1
-> FAIL Installing Net::SSH2 failed. See /root/.cpanm/build.log for details.
```

I found on other forums that line that says

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
```

means  I am missing glibc-static package. However I am running this on CentOS 5 and there is no glibc-static package in any of repositories? Is there some other alternative name for this package or I am going in wrong direction?

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, -lz, refers to libz, the zlib compression library.  I'm sure CentOS has that -- you probably want to install the "zlib-devel" package.